# Angular2 FormBuilder blur validation: how do I disable?

Tags: angular

With Angular 2 `FormBuilder`, when I have a form control that has validation and I focus and then unfocus, the validation rules are triggered and the control will have an error set on it.

How can I disable this universally for `blur` or `focusout`?

I tried this directive, and it works, but it's very hacky and also doesn't work unless the `input` field is a child of a form with the `[formGroup]` attribute set because otherwise I get a `Error: No provider for NgControl!` error:

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: 'input'
})
export class InputDirective {
    constructor(private formControl: NgControl) {}

    @HostListener('focusout')
    onFocusOut() {
        this.formControl.control.markAsUntouched(true);
    }
}
```

Isn't there some kind of way to just set global rules for the form builder?

This error is annoying because if I click into an input field and then attempt to click a button below it without first entering enough data to make the field "valid", then on click of the button the validation error I have will appear and it moves the screen down, thus preventing the click of the button because it moves down too far for the click to work.

For instance:

[image]

As you can see in the GIF above, when I click off the input field the validator is triggered and it sets an error on the field, thus making the error message appear and messing up my button click.

Granted, this is my own issue because I have the error message there, but I want to disable the error checking on `focusout` all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control when the validation messages appear using ngIf. Something like this:

```
                <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(productNameVar.touched ||
                                                 productNameVar.dirty || product.id !== 0) &&
                                                 productNameVar.errors">
                    <span *ngIf="productNameVar.errors.required">
                        Product name is required.
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="productNameVar.errors.minlength">
                        Product name must be at least three characters.
                    </span>
                </span>
```

Alternatively, since you are using reactive forms you could write a generic validator and completely control how and when the messages appear.

Here is one I use:

```
processMessages(container: FormGroup): { [key: string]: string } {
    let messages = {};
    for (let controlKey in container.controls) {
        if (container.controls.hasOwnProperty(controlKey)) {
            let c = container.controls[controlKey];
            // If it is a FormGroup, process its child controls.
            if (c instanceof FormGroup) {
                let childMessages = this.processMessages(c);
                Object.assign(messages, childMessages);
            } else {
                // Only validate if there are validation messages for the control
                if (this.validationMessages[controlKey]) {
                    messages[controlKey] = '';
                    if ((c.dirty || c.touched) && c.errors) {
                        Object.keys(c.errors).map(messageKey => {
                            if (this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey]) {
                                messages[controlKey] += this.validationMessages[controlKey][messageKey] + ' ';
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return messages;
}
```

I can then control what gets added to the messages array and therefore what shows up as a message to the user.

You can see the complete code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms In the APM folder.

UPDATE

But now that you've updated your question to include an example that only has one input element, the above may be overkill.

Comment: Oddly enough I used your example a while back for my error messages component. In there, I show the error if the form is touched. That is my problem :) gotta update that condition. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it is an easy fix!